# Gradle plugin development error passing arguments

Tags: plugins, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to create a custom gradle plugin following the example here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/gradle-custom-plugin.html. Everything works fine as long as I dont try to provide arguments to the task, however when I attempt to add arguments, I receive the following error:

> Error:(26, 0) Task of type 'com.jwoolston.finalizer.gradle.FinalizerTask_Decorated' has been instantiated directly which is not supported. Tasks can only be created using the DSL.

I've googled it but I don't seem to be getting any results related to my situation (at least not that I understand.

The plugin short id is declared in the generated jar's manifest as: `finalizer-plugin`.

I have the following files:

**FinalizerPlugin.groovy**

```
class FinalizerArgumentExtension {
    String path = ''
}

class FinalizerPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create('finalizeArgs', FinalizerArgumentExtension)
        project.task('finalizeTask', type: FinalizerTask)
    }
}
```

**FinalizerTask.groovy**

```
class FinalizerTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    def executeTask() {
        println "------------executeTask-------------------"
        println "Source Directory : ${project.finalizeArgs.path}"
    }
}
```

Plugin related exerpt of **build.gradle** of the utilizing project:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

version = '1.0.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url uri("file://C:\\Users\\ideal\\.m2\\repository")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.jwoolston.finalizer',
                name: 'gradle',
                version: '1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'finalizer-plugin'

finalizeArgs {
    path = "src/main/java"
}
```

In short, I don't understand the error. Near as I can tell, everything matches the tutorial. I am trying to simply pass in a string argument to the plugin's task.

Comment: Chances are that you are pulling an old version from the local Maven repo.

Comment: That was my thought as well so I changed the version number to be certain and the same thing happened.

Comment: OK, then I'm out of ideas. All I can say is that I could reproduce your error, and that my fixes to the bugs in your code solved the problem for me. Try to strip down the code, and put the plugin/task class right into the build script (instead of having a `buildscript` block). Perhaps this will help to find the problem.

Comment: If I move the plugin/finalizeArgs lines into the buildscript block,  it complains about not being able to find the plugin. If I comment out the buildscript block, having the repositories and dependencies in the main level of the file, it complains about `classpath` not being available in the DSL. The strange thing to me is it all worked prior to adding the finalizeArgs closure and its corresponding groovy class.

Comment: I said "*instead* of having a `buildscript` block". The `apply` has to change to `apply plugin: FinalizerPlugin`.

Answer (score -1):

Plugin class needs to be fixed as follows:

```
class FinalizerPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) { ... }
}
```

Groovy only supports String interpolation for double-quoted Strings:

```
println "Source Directory : ${project.finalizeArgs.path}"
```

Comment: I made the suggested changes, but there was no difference in result.

Comment: Works just fine for me (with my changes). Perhaps you didn't save the file(s) after making the changes?

Comment: I wish it was that simple. I double checked everything, and I am still seeing the error. I even changed the version numbers to make sure I'm getting the up to date files. Perhaps I am not running the correct tasks? I even tried running only the clean task an I still get the error.

Comment: Chances are that you are overlooking something (e.g. `Project o` vs. `Project project`), or that your code is more complicated than what you have shown here. The error shown in your post happens in the configuration phase, so it doesn't matter which task is run.

Comment: I have updated the code samples in the question to reflect the current state, and included the entirety of the build.gradle file. I was very careful to make sure I corrected the project variable name. This is all in IntelliJ if it makes a difference.